# Differnce between gcvt() and _gcvt() in C

Tags: c

I would like to convert a double into character string and I find `gcvt()` and `_gcvt()`. I just wondering what is the difference between them. Both return with `char*` and both need value, number of digits and buffer as a given parameters

Comment: Why not read the documentation?

Comment: It says identical, but something have to be different between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [google search result](https://users.pja.edu.pl/%7Ejms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/src/gcvt.html)

> *The `_gcvt()` function is identical to `gcvt()`. Use `_gcvt()` for ANSI/ISO naming conventions.*